# Is there any way to do pattern matching with function decomposition in scala?

Tags: scala

I really want to know how to do pattern matching with  function decomposition in scala like the below.

```
def map(list:List[Int],f:Int=>Int):List[Int]= list match {
 case x::xs => f(x)::map(xs,f)}
```

Is there any form like this?
f is function `Int => Int`

```
f match {
  case (x=>x) => (2*x=>x)
}
```

My aim is to decompose the function in pattern matching.

Comment: No, because that would require some notion of equality over functions. For example, should `x => 2*x` and `x => x*2` be equal? One one hand, they result in the same byte code, but on another hand they have different ASTs. What about `x => 2*x` and `x => (2*x)`?

Comment: I can only find function composition for scala.... BTW, I really don't understand what do you wanna do by this, maybe you can write some pseudo code for your idea?

Comment: In the functional programming principles class where martin odersky teachs,[It's a link](https://github.com/tonyskn/coursera-scala/blob/master/w2-funsets/src/main/scala/funsets/FunSets.scala)
I solved the problem like below.
**def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = (e:Int) => exists(s,x=>f(x)==e)**
But, I want to solve this problem using pattern matching.

Comment: Hey, can you please edit the question? Your `map` as is defined here is perfectly valid, you just need to add the case for Nil. E.g. invoking `map(List(1,2,3,4), (x: Int) => x + 1)` will yield `List(2, 3, 4, 5)`. What does this have to do with decomposition? I get from the second part of the question that you want to pattern match on the `f`, but the `map` part is confusing. And as @Alec said, no you can't pattern match on the function, although from your use case I don't see the reason why you need to.

Comment: `case (x=>x) => (2*x=>x)` what would that even mean?

Comment: Thank you for your pleasure.
I just wonder are there any kinds of parttern matching in aspect of function.
@slouc Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand of your question, you are asking how to define the map operation on a function.

There is no need at all to pattern match, and as @Alec says it is impossible to define a notion of equality over functions.

But mathematically, you could notice that applying map on a function **g** on a function **f** is exactly **f(g(x))**. So according to the [Scala Documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Function1.html) :

```
def map(f: Int => Boolean, g: Int => Int): Int => Boolean = f.compose(g)
```